# How do you get the git branch name for a given shasum?

Tags: git, branch

For example I have this commit `fa33745860726a363287962232787f23585a46e9`, I want to know which branch it belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$ git branch --contains fa33745860726a363287962232787f23585a46e9
```